# Simplify the number of for loop of exhaustive search in Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I want to find an objective result using exhaustive search in Matlab. Let's say that I have a vector/matrix 'x' as below:

```
x = [a b c;d e f]; a,b,c,d,e,f are Boolean (i.e., 0 or 1)
```

Based on 'x', I have 2^6 number of decisions. Generally, we can use 'for loop' to solve this problem:

```
for t1=0:1
   a = t1;
   for t2=0:1
      b = t2;
         .....
         for t6=0:1
            f = t6;
            g = a + ... + c + d + ... + f;
         end
       .....
    end
end
```

However, it would be burdensome if the number of elements increases. Is there any other way to simplify the looping without adding many 'for loop'?

Comment: When you change the values of `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`,  `e` and `f` after defining `x`, it doesn't update `x` as per the new values. Looking at your question, it seems to me that you're mistaken about how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the number of elements of `x` using [`numel`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/numel.html). Generate all possible combinations in base 10 using [`colon`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) operator. Convert them to a base 2 character vector using [`dec2bin`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dec2bin.html). Separate them in individual double elements by subtracting `'0'`. Now [`sum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) over the second dimension to get `g`.

```
g = sum(dec2bin(0:2^numel(x)-1)-'0', 2);
```

---

Note that as number of variables increase, more memory would be needed. e.g. with your example with 30 variables (30 such variables in workspace is not a good idea), 8.2 GB memory would be needed for `g` and there will be more memory needed for processing. You can do something like this for such a case:

```
g = repmat(uint8(0),1,2^numel(x));
for k = 0:2^numel(x)-1
    g(k+1) = sum(dec2bin(k)-'0', 2);
end
```

But be aware that `uint8` has its limits (0-255)

Comment: Thanks, it works. However, when I use 30 variables, it eats a lot of memory. I think it can only be used for small-scale of variables.

Comment: @bnbfreak Obv memory would be issue. That requires 8.2 GB of memory for `g`. There will be a tradeoff btw memory and speed. You can get some saving with `uint`/ `single` /  looping for every single value. But you have to comprise between speed and memory according to what actually you're really dealing with and how much memory you have. Having 30 such dynamic variables in the workspace is a very bad idea anyway

Comment: Yes, that would be a problem for me as in fact, I need to increase the number of variables maybe up to more than 100 variables.